# How can I show every second of a timer in the console while the apps runs?

Tags: swift

Our app currently is not timing out at the correct time, so I wanted to display every second of the timer in the console to see what is going on. Any ideas on how to do this. The Timer is part of the Timer class.

Comment: not quite clear why you can't. what did you try, and what didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

```
let timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in 
    print("Sometext")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the time each time the timer fires you could adapt Владимир's answer slightly:

```
let _ =  Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    print("Timer fired at at \(DateFormatter.localizedString(from:Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .medium))")
}
```